# Binding a function to a key is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, key-bindings

My code:

```
import tkinter

master = tkinter.Tk()
master.title("test1")
master.geometry("300x300")

masterFrame = tkinter.Frame(master)

masterFrame.pack(fill=tkinter.X)

checkboxArea = tkinter.Frame(masterFrame, height=26)

checkboxArea.pack(fill=tkinter.X)

inputStuff = tkinter.Frame(masterFrame)

checkboxList = []

def drawCheckbox():
    checkboxList.append(entry.get())
    entry.delete(0,tkinter.END)
    checkboxRow = tkinter.Frame(checkboxArea)
    checkboxRow.pack(fill=tkinter.X)
    checkbox1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(checkboxRow, text = checkboxList[-1])
    checkbox1.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
    deleteItem = tkinter.Button(checkboxRow, text = "x", command=checkboxRow.destroy, bg="red", fg="white", activebackground="white", activeforeground="red")
    deleteItem.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)

def bindToEnter():
    master.bind('<Return>', drawCheckbox)

def createInputStuff():
    paddingFrame = tkinter.Frame(inputStuff, height=5)
    paddingFrame.pack(fill=tkinter.X)
    buttonDone.pack()
    inputStuff.pack()
    buttonAdd.pack_forget()
    bindToEnter()

def removeInputStuff():
    inputStuff.pack_forget()
    buttonAdd.pack()
    buttonDone.remove()

buttonDone = tkinter.Button(inputStuff, text = "Close Input", command=removeInputStuff)


buttonAdd = tkinter.Button(masterFrame, text="Add Item", command=createInputStuff)
buttonAdd.pack()


topInput = tkinter.Frame(inputStuff)
bottomInput = tkinter.Frame(inputStuff)

topInput.pack()
bottomInput.pack()

prompt = tkinter.Label(topInput, text="What do you want your checkbox to be for?")
prompt.pack()
entry = tkinter.Entry(bottomInput, bd=3)
entry.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
buttonConfirm = tkinter.Button(bottomInput, text="Confirm", command=drawCheckbox)
buttonConfirm.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

master.mainloop()
```

The idea is to have pressing Return/Enter do the same thing as hitting the "Confirm" button, running drawCheckbox. This is still a work in progress, I'll unbind the drawCheckbox function from the Enter key when removeInputStuff is run. Nevertheless, I still don't get why pressing the Enter key doesn't run the function it's bound to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind a function `fct` to a key (or any other kind of event), the function is called with one argument like that `fct(event)`, `event` having various attributes depending on the kind of event (mouse position, ...). Your problem is that the function you call `drawCheckbox` does not take any argument, so every time you press Enter, it raises an error

> TypeError: drawCheckbox() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

To correct it you can either define your function with a default argument,

```
def drawCheckbox(event=None):
    ...
```

or you can use a lambda function to do the binding

```
master.bind('<Return>', lambda event: drawCheckbox())
```